# What is the source of this story?

Tags: yom-kippur, story-identification

What is the source of this story found in many non-traditional machzorim?

*Late one Yom Kippur afternoon in Berdichev, Rabbi Levi Yitzhaq went up and argued with God that his people deserved to be saved.  He was about to sway Him!  Then, out of the corner of his eye, he glanced down and noticed that Hayyim, the laundry man, had fainted from hunger.  He started to rush back down to conclude the service so that Hayyim could eat.  The angels went after him, saying, "Reb Yitzhaq, what about saving the world?"  He answered, "Where is it written that saving the world must come at the price of the life of Hayyim, the laundry man?" And he rushed back to conclude the service.  And he heard a chorus of angels calling after him: "Levi Yitzhaq, you ARE saving the world!"*

Very inspirational, but weak in teaching Judaism:

-If you faint from hunger, eat. Yom Kippur or not.  Your life comes first.  (Pikuach nefesh.)

-Yom Kippur ends at sundown, 25 hours after it begins, whether or not the prayers have been completed.  You can rush and daven Neilah at noon, but that won't make Yom Kippur end any sooner.

So does anyone know its source?

Comment: Are you asking where the story comes from, or are you asking for a solution to the problems posed?

Comment: Where the story comes from and if it's a genuine folktale.  It bothers me that it misses two Jewish teachings.

Comment: If you faint from hunger you don't have permission to eat. You don't die from fainting. If there is 10 minutes left of the fast and you faint, just wait lying down for 10 minutes (unless you have some special medical condition or whatever that puts you at risk of immediate death)

Comment: "Non-Traditional Machzorim" Do you mean Nusach Sefard machzorim? Reform machzorim? What does this mean?

Comment: what do we mean by genuine folktale? :)

Comment: @Double AA -- The piece said Reb Yitzhak rushed back to save the man's LIFE.  Besides, there is always strong doubt about whether life is actually in danger.  When someone faints from hunger, you feed him, period.

Comment: @Maurice Are you a doctor? Why are you making these broad factual claims about when there is danger or not? Every case is different. Period.

Comment: @Double AA -- It's precisely because I am NOT a doctor that I say that, when there is doubt, assume there is danger to life.  (This may be a new topic: When do you know whether to apply pikuach nefesh?  Has it been answered before?)

Comment: You didn't say when there is doubt feed him. You said if he faints feed him. That's different. If you have a real doubt then indeed you feed him. Not all fainting is reason for doubt, at least not to all people. As I said above, every case is different. Period.

Comment: @Ezra -- I mean machzorim that intersperse sayings and reflections in English with the required prayers.